# How to change apperance of the form after InfoPath customization

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, office-365

I’ve got a question – How to change look of the form after edited using InfoPath? I use SharePoint Online (Office 365) always I use InfoPath to change form in SharePoint the appearance has change (it is no default like standard form).
How I can change back the previously look of this form?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto List Settings > Form Options (Under General) > Use the default SharePoint form.

Comment: You will have the option to also delete the InfoPath form if you wish when you do that.